# Why does QUADPACK only enforce the least strict error boundary?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

According to [this reference](http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/manuals/html/gsl-ref-html/gsl-ref_16.html#SEC244) (which is in agreement with my own numerical experiments), [QUADPACK](http://www.netlib.org/quadpack/) tries to fulfill the following accuracy requirement on the approximation error:

> |RESULT - I| $\le$ max(epsabs, epsrel |I|),

where $I$ is the actual value of the integral.

Why does it only fulfill the less strict error boundary and not both of them? Wouldn't it make more sense to try to fulfill

> |RESULT - I| $\le$ min(epsabs, epsrel |I|)

or something similar?

The question came up in the context of an integral with a small absolute value, where the above behavior leads to the error estimate being larger than the estimated integral value due to

> |RESULT - I| $\le$ epsabs

being fulfilled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally, I just stumbled upon the answer to my own question, in [this answer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/26743-absolute-and-relative-tolerance-definitions) in the Matlab Answers community.

The idea is that generally, the relative error boundary is the one that one would like to fulfill. However, when approaching very small integral values, the error boundary imposed by the relative tolerance becomes extremely small. It is in this case that the absolute error boundary is used as a more practical restriction.